# Why does CSS height create a gap in this jsFiddle example?

Tags: css

See this jsFiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/M4FAr/

CSS:

```
a {display:inline-block;background:gold}
a > * {display:inline-block;margin:0}
p {width:auto;line-height:30px;background:yellowgreen}
div {width:30px;height:30px;background:orangered}​
```

HTML:

```
<a>
    <p>left</p>
    <div></div>
</a>​
```

Now, why does setting `height:30px` to the `div` on the right create a gap above the `p` on the left? And how do I get rid of it?

I just want the container `a` to be 30 pixels heigh and no more. Also, I want its children to line up.

Comment: Please post your code here. If jsFiddle goes down, your question is useless.

Comment: Clarify what you want it to look like in the end?

Comment: that extra space can be produced from default behavior of P tag.

Comment: This has to do with vertical-align (add `vertical-align: top` on one of them) and/or lack of actual content in `div` element but I didn't dig any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `a > * {float:left}` solved my problem...

```
a {display:inline-block;background:gold}
a > * {margin:0;float:left}
p {line-height:30px;background:yellowgreen}
div {width:30px;height:30px;background:orangered}​
```

Comment: Note that `float: left;` overrides `display: inline-block;`

Comment: why you want elements inside a to be inline-block?

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili, I guess I don't. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this can solve the problem:

```
p {
   vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: This solves the lining up, but there is still a gap at the bottom of the `a` tag's content.

Answer (score -1):

Because both the `<p>` and `<div>` are inline elements, they align to their baseline.

In the case of your `<div>`, it has no text, therefore its base is its baseline.

In the case of your `<p>`, its base will be the baseline of the vertically centred text.

There are various ways to apply `vertical-align` to override the default alignment.

Comment: The text isn't vertically-centered. It's line-height: 30px. I'm still unable to get this to work. Can you modify the jsFiddle to work?

Comment: @sfjedi Try `a > * {display:inline-block;margin:0;vertical-align:bottom;}`